# Can we make one Layout type for all screen size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, material-design

I developed apps using multiple layouts types for different screens types and resolutions but I have notices that some developers using only one layout type,Which one is a better practices to continue with Single or Multiple layout type?

> Multiple layout type like

```
layout-large-mdpi   
layout-large-tvdpi  
layout-large-xhdpi 
layout-xlarge-mdpi  
layout-xlarge-xhdpi
```

Comment: use Constraint Layout for designing the screens, Hope so it helps you and avoid giving static values for width and height,

Comment: @SandeepManmode ,Yes Sir i never use statics values but what about the ImageView how do you define that ,i sometimes define static values.

Comment: @Abhishek you are talking about *layout-large-mdpi* layout type

Comment: @AndroidGeek No. I am talking about keep layout file in layout folder & use values (like width, height) from different values folders like "values-large" or "values-normal" .

Comment: Ok , that would be great @Abhishek

Comment: @AndroidGeek I have added my answer. Check it if helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Using different dimens files you can do this thing.**

values-mdpi ->dimens.xml

values-hdpi  ->dimens.xml

values-xhdpi ->dimens.xml

values-xxhdpi ->dimens.xml

For example:
define one in **values-mdpi ->dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="scale_1dp">10dp</dimen>
```

and for **values-hdpi  ->dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="scale_1dp">12dp</dimen>
```

and for **values-xhdpi ->dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="scale_1dp">15dp</dimen>
```

And after that use this dimen

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="@dimen/scale_1dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

**same thing for text size.**

Answer (score 0):

**This make scene**

> Note : Recommended way is different.

```
//first create layout xml in layout folder in my case it's 
//sample_activity.xml below is the xml code.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="This is button"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

> Look in above code I am taking values for Button height and width from dimens file which is in values folder. By default layout folder points to normal screen size and values folder points to normal screen size.
>
> Now we have to create different values folders for different screen size. Like values(for normal), values-large(for large screen), values-small(for small screen size), values-xlarge(for extra large screen size). Create dimens.xml file in all folders.
>
> So first values/dimens.xml file is like below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

 <dimen name="button_width">100dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="button_height">50dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

> Second values-large/dimens.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>

 <dimen name="button_width">200dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="button_height">100dp</dimen>

 </resources>
```

> Third values-small/dimens.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>

  <dimen name="button_width">10dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="button_height">50dp</dimen>

  </resources>
```

> Fourth values-xlarge/dimens.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>

  <dimen name="button_width">200dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="button_height">100dp</dimen>

  </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the app can adapt to different screen sizes, but you have to create different layouts for the different sizes.

Then the system will select the correct layout based on the screen size of the device.