# How to target font sizes for different screen densities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-screen-support

I am developing an android tablet application. To support different screen sizes I am using resource qualifiers

> - sw600dp - Nexus 7 like screens
> - sw768dp - Nexus 9 sized screens
> - sw800dp - Nexus 10 sized screens
> - sw840dp - Pixel C Sized screens

Now I came across a situation where the same 10 inch screen has different densities.

> Nexus 10 @density 2.0
>
> Kindle Fire 10 @density 1.5

Both these devices are fetching the values from the **sw800dp** folder. But in nexus 10 the font sizes are normal and on Kindle Fire 10 HD the font sizes are very large.

What's the best way to target these two types of screens?

Also am I following the correct method in targeting multiple screen sizes?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524010/can-we-make-one-layout-type-for-all-screen-size/47524265#47524265) solution this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

For Nexus 10 font size, create res folder. by default is portrait.

```
values-sw720dp-land
```

[image]
Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

Make folders like this

values             // default values

values-sw400dp

values-sw600dp

values-sw800dp

create dimen file in each folder for diffrent screen wise size